# How to make 1920X1080 resolution video as background with full video visibility?

Tags: html, css, video

I tried like this, But I'dint get full video visibility. eg: May be 1920X1080 video and have window size 1366x768 so miss matching.

And also i tried like giving width as auto and height as 100% then I can see full video visible but space on both side of video. So i need without space.

```
    <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay muted>
       <source src="img/xxxxx.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
```

css

```
html,body{overflow:hidden;}
.general video { height: auto; width: 100%; position: absolute; top:0;}
```

-thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove the margin and the padding from the html and body. Remove the controls from the player. Press F11 in the browser for full screen mode:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="">
  <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <!-- Safari / iOS, IE9 -->
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm">
      <!-- Chrome10+, Ffx4+, Opera10.6+ -->
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <!-- Firefox3.6+ / Opera 10.5+ -->
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you, this one I already tried. I need same thing without scrolling. with full video visible.

Comment: I've added support for other browsers. Full screen now works in chrome, firefox, and IE11. You can try by click "Run code snippet", "Full page", and then F11 in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The space you mean is maybe the default `padding` and `margin`.

Try this

```
*{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: what about overflow: hidden;

Comment: I gave it  because no scrolling. Yes your rite but not your answer is matching my question.

Comment: Is this the only code in your file, or is there anything else?

Comment: Yes, Materialize css library is there. So in that they already made these kind of resetting things and all thats why I dint putted these stuffs. I thought its understandable.

Comment: Do you have a demo or link? I can not imagine why this should not work

Comment: To understand that without scrolling need full video visible so I gave body and html as overflow hidden.

Comment: Did you understand question space means not this kind of space there is video ratio and browser window ratio are differ so there is more space on both left & right side of video if i gave height as 100% and width auto. And I dont need these space. Leave it space i need full visibility video if i made video as background.